# How to mask/clip the window in javafx

Tags: javafx

I am working on javafx where the requirement is to mask/clip the particular screen when any of the button is clicked on that screen. When the button is clicked, until we receive the response I should restrict the users in accessing other options/buttons in the page. User need to wait until the request is processed. While requests get processing,I need to make my main window disable/mask/clip(I am not sure of exact term). How could i do this?

I am using java 1.7_25 & javafx 2x and consuming the services via Rest API calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setDisable()` method and `WAIT` cursor on the root node until the request is processed,

```
//on process running
main_window.setCursor(Cursor.WAIT);
main_window.setDisable(true);

//on-finished
main_window.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
main_window.setDisable(false);
```